# Local file upload to S3 using Filepicker on Android device

Tags: android, filepicker.io, filepicker

I am trying to upload local video files from Android App to S3 bucket using Filepicker (https://www.filepicker.io). As per github documentation, below is the sample code. The url mentioned below is for the local file url, however, I would like to set few parameters like the S3 location to save the file, policy & signature and not sure where and how to set it. 
Can somebody shed some light here? 
Appreciate any help.

```
final String url = "PUT PATH TO LOCAL FILE HERE - something like content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A64";

Filepicker.uploadLocalFile(Uri.parse(url), this, new FilepickerCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onFileUploadSuccess(FPFile fpFile) {
      // Do something on success
    }

    @Override
    public void onFileUploadError(Throwable error) {
      // Do something on error
    }

    @Override
    public void onFileUploadProgress(Uri uri, float progress) {
      // Do something on progress
    }
});
```

Comment: That is no path to a local file. It's a content scheme.

Comment: A file picker that uploads a file? Whats in a name!

Comment: final String url = "PUT PATH TO LOCAL FILE HERE

Comment: Well put a path then! Why mentioning that content scheme? Confusing!

Comment: Well, I would like to set the store options, like below.
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Filepicker.class);
intent.putExtra("location", "S3");
intent.putExtra("path", "/example/123.png");
intent.putExtra("container", "example_bucket");
intent.putExtra("access", "public");

Answer (score 0):

Filepicker is now Filestack.

You might have better luck with this repo:
https://github.com/filestack/filestack-android

I will also say that this repo is currently being reviewed and updated. 
If you have questions you can create an issue on the repo or submit a ticket to Filestack's support team

Comment: Thanks for the input @Flutterby_Dev. I am referring to filestack-android and created an issue already but No response yet :( . I can try submitting a ticket.

Comment: Filestack is actually currently working to push a new Android SDK.

Comment: Thanks @Flutterby_Dev. I got it working by directly accessing the Filepicker API and passing through retrofit.